# FeatureUnion and Pipeline to select columns of a matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn

It's your boy here.

I am currently struggling with some shenanigans with scikit-learn FeatureUnion and Pipeline combination.

1) I have the .csv data of the features and the target

2) Also, I have the image data that has been loaded and transformed to np.array of np.arrays

3) I have splitted it into train (train_idx and img_train) and test (test_idx and img_test) with StratifiedShuffleSplit.

To call the train features of the .csv data I type train_idx[0], its shape is (792, 192).

To call the train features of the image data I type img_train[0], its shape is (792, 4816).

The according shapes of train_idx[1] and img_train[1], which are the targets, are (792,) and (792,)

The task here is to apply PCA() to img_train and leave train_idx as it is, and then pass them to RandomForestClassifier. First of all, they should be stored in a np.matrix. My code is the following:

```
# define functions that pass columns of matrix to FeatureUnion
def select_col_idx(matrix, cols):
      return X_train[:, cols]
def select_col_img(matrix, cols):
      return X_train[:, cols]

A_train = np.matrix((train_idx[0].T, train_idx[1], img_train[0].T, img_train[1]))
```

A_train has a shape of (1, 4). Is it strange?

Anyway, the code below shows my pipe:

```
subpipe = Pipeline([('caller', FunctionTransformer(select_col_img, validate=False, kw_args={'cols': [2, 3]})),
                ('pca', PCA(n_components=4, random_state=RANDOM_SEED))])


subpipe_2 = Pipeline([('caller', FunctionTransformer(select_col_idx, validate=False, kw_args={'cols': [0, 1]})),
                 ('none', None)])

features = FeatureUnion([('subpipe', subpipe), ('subpipe2', subpipe_2)])

pipe = Pipeline([('features_union', features), ('rf', rf)])
```

Then, I try to `pipe.fit(A_train)` which doesn't work.
To tell the truth, I cannot even fit with the `subpipe.fit(A_train)` because I receive 'setting an array element with a sequence' error.

I understand it is a problem with the data extraction, but I have literally spent hours trying to solve it. I have even tried to perform the same stuff on a simple np.array, not a np.matrix, but still no luck.

I feel exhausted...

Thank you for everything in advance Q(^,^Q)

P.S. Do we really need python `Class` to extract columns?

**Post-edited:**

As I have already written, `subpipe.fit(A_train)` does not work. The full traceback of an error is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/komplett/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 270, in fit
self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
File "/home/komplett/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 307, in fit
self._fit(X)
File "/home/komplett/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 346, in _fit
copy=self.copy)
File "/home/komplett/.local/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

However, I can fit the second subpipe as `subpipe_2.fit(A_train)` which gives a perfectly normal fit:

```
 Pipeline(steps=[('caller', FunctionTransformer(accept_sparse=False,
      func=<function select_col_idx at 0x7fc954345b70>,
      inv_kw_args=None, inverse_func=None, kw_args={'cols': [0, 1]},
      pass_y=False, validate=False)), ('none', None)])
```

**Post-post-edited**

Okay, if I execute `X = select_col_idx(A_train, cols=[0, 1])` it returns the matrix of two matrices, where `X[:, 0]` is the features (train_idx[0].T) and `X[:, 1]` is the targets (train_idx[1]). Note that `[X.dtype == object]` is `[true]`.

Nevertheless, if I try to fit the FunctionTransformer as mentioned below, I receive the traceback error above, the one with the 'setting an array element with the sequence':

```
X = FunctionTransformer(select_col_img, kw_args={'cols': [2, 3]})
X.fit_transform(A_train)
# output is the traceback error
```

I receive the same error with the 'select_col_idx' function.

So, what I am thinking is I need to fix the extraction method. It should divide that matrix of matrices into two different *variables* which are invididually passed as **X** and **y** to any .fit, because simply .fit(X) does not work and returns that 'setting an array ...' error. Seems like 'OK' logic to me but it is cumbersome.

Why would anyone tell me to store the data in a np.matrix in the first place! Anyway, is it possible to fix this method?

**Post-post-post edited**

The train_idx looks like this:

```
[array([[ 0.001953,  0.      ,  0.      , ...,  0.010742,  0.      ,
     0.017578],
   [ 0.003906,  0.005859,  0.074219, ...,  0.02832 ,  0.      ,
     0.051758],
   [ 0.013672,  0.005859,  0.019531, ...,  0.      ,  0.024414,
     0.029297],
   ..., 
   [ 0.011719,  0.013672,  0.048828, ...,  0.017578,  0.      ,
     0.019531],
   [ 0.027344,  0.044922,  0.009766, ...,  0.      ,  0.024414,
     0.051758],
   [ 0.046875,  0.10742 ,  0.015625, ...,  0.008789,  0.006836,  0.      
   ]]), array([ 4,  6, 56, 29, 94, 22, 94, 16,  0, 53, 87, 67, 51, 97,  5, 98, 44,
   43, 66, 81, 80, 67, 42, 67, 40, 34, 91, 88,  0, 13, 53, 89, 32, 72,
   22, 79, 26, 84, 79,  3, 25, 19, 87, 18, 48,  5,  2, 28, 66,  2, 83,
   22, 10, 84, 58, 55, 76, 52,  3, 84, 44, 65,  9, 51,  9, 58, 52, 44, ...  6, 28, 25])]
```

img_train is equal but the first array is presented like below:

```
[array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
   ..., 
   [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
   [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

So the first array of train_idx is the features, and the second one is the targets. To be more precise, the features are the characteristics of width, margin, length etc. of tree leaves (as far as I know). The targets are the classes of such leaves (their biological names). The first array of img_train is the pixels of input images which have been previously normalized. I have loaded them with the following function:

```
def load_img(path):
img_data = []
for i in range(1, 101):
    flist = glob.glob(path + str(i) + '.png')
    for j in flist:
        img_data.append(scipy.misc.imread(j))

return np.array(img_data)
```

Then, I have applied StratifiedShuffle on img_data.

Thank you again for the response, Vivek!

Comment: Can you execute `subpipe.fit()` and `subpipe_2.fit()`? If not, please post the full stack trace of error.

Comment: Can you try that again using `matrix[:, cols]` in your function definitions?

Comment: I have added the information. Hope it is exactly what you required!

Comment: Ok now that I have read your question more thoroghly, you say that shape of `train_idx[0]` is `(792, 4816)`. So whats the shape of `train_idx`? Scikit estimators only support 2-d arrays of shape `[n_samples, n_features]`.

Comment: Hm, the img_train[0].shape is (792, 4816). The shape of train_idx[0] is (792, 192). I cannot call train_idx.shape because it is a 'list'. The same stuff with img_train. It is like an array of two arrays.
:)

Comment: Ok, what does train_idx contain? For img_train its maybe the rows and columns of a single image. Correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. I have added the data information in the **edited** section in the end. I have to go now, so I'll tune later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

After giving it some thought I actually came up with a solution, though, the data are stored in `np.array`, not in required `np.matrix` format. Note that `rf = RandomForestClassifier()`:

```
A_train = np.array((train_idx[0].T, train_idx[1],
                    img_train[0].T, img_train[1]))

def select_train_cols(X_train, cols):
    return X_train[cols].T

def megapipe():
    subpipe = Pipeline(
        [('caller', FunctionTransformer(select_train_cols, validate=False, kw_args={'cols': 0})),
         ('none', None)])
    subpipe_2 = Pipeline(
        [('caller', FunctionTransformer(select_train_cols, validate=False, kw_args={'cols': 2})),
         ('pca', pca)])
    fu = FeatureUnion([('subpipe', subpipe),
                       ('subpipe_2', subpipe_2)])
    megapipe = Pipeline([('fu', fu),
                         ('rf', rf)])
    return megapipe
```

It is possible therefore to implement `megapipe.fit(A_train, train_idx[1])` which does not yield errors!

It seems implementing `np.matrix` method is just impractical and inapt... or at least I hope so.

Thanks.

**Edited**

So, there is actually a solution to it using `np.concatenate()`:

```
A_train = np.concatenate((train_idx[0], img_train[0]), axis=1)
A_test = np.concatenate((test_idx[0], img_test[0]), axis=1)

def select_col_idx(X, col_idx=[1]):
return X[:, col_idx]
```

Then, you will call `FunctionTransformer` for *train_idx* data like the following:

```
FunctionTransformer(select_col_idx, kw_args={'col_idx': np.arange(0, 192)}
```

To apply `PCA()` to *img_train* you just grab the rest data columns and pass it within the pipe as stated earlier.

Fit and predict will work just fine with `.fit(A_train, *labels)` and `.predict(A_test, *labels)`

This topic from now on may be considered redundant.

Thank you.